# Why OpenDDS Transport not working when NAT is disabled in VPN?

Tags: tcp, firewall, nat, data-distribution-service, opendds

I tested on localhost it works
Tested following RTPS.ini/ TCP.ini (local IP) /using info repo.ior

I tested with connecting two PCs with VPN (publisher on PC_A and subscriber on PC_B, PC_A runs DDS repo)
it did not work. NAT is disabled. windows defender is running

I used the following ini same used for localhost test for VPN test on two PCs
rtps.ini

```
[common] 
DCPSGlobalTransportConfig=$file 
DCPSDefaultDiscovery=DEFAULT_RTPS 

[transport/the_rtps_transport] 
transport_type=rtps_udp
```

tcp.ini on PC_A and PC_B

```
[common]
DCPSDebugLevel=0
DCPSInfoRepo=corbaloc::192.168.56.9:12345/DCPSInfoRepo  # PC_A IP 192.168.56.9
DCPSGlobalTransportConfig=config1

[config/config1]
transports=tcp1

[transport/tcp1]
transport_type=tcp
```

Comment: Have you made exceptions for OpenDDS in Defender? Also what kind of VPN are you using? RTPS discovery requires multicast to work and I don't think every VPN supports multicast.

Comment: @Fred Hornsey yes my VPN does not support multicast.. I just found it.... thanks for that... also I want to know **Have you made exceptions for OpenDDS in Defender?** what are these exceptions?  i did not change anything in defender

Comment: What I meant is that is that if the firewall is unchanged, then it will block OpenDDS from communicating with another computer.

Comment: @Fred Hornsey should I disable the firewall all the time? or should I make a change to a defender in order to communicate with another PC with open? what should I change?

Comment: You could disable the firewall temporarily if you want to confirm that it is the problem, but long term you will need to make changes to the firewall to allow OpenDDS through. I'm not a regular Windows user, so I couldn't tell you how to do that myself, but it should be easy to look it up with a search. What ports number and type (TCP vs. UDP) to allow will depend on the transport and discovery configuration being used. There should be information the port in the OpenDDS Developers Guide Chapter 7.

Comment: @Fred Hornsey Actually, I cannot disable the firewall...lts not allowed from my institute.... is this you mean firewall exceptions https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9sLSCyOk0s&ab_channel=HOWZA    should I allow domain/ public/ private and group for both publisher.exe and subscriber.exe? (control panel --> allow apps to communicate through windows defender firewall)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about. I have no idea if your VPN would be classified under public or private, but it sounds like you're going in the right direction overall. If you're at an "institute", there should be some IT people available that could give you better help than I could, especially if they set up the VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked for me

control panel -> allows apps to communicate through the windows defender firewall

allow domain/private/public according to your setup for following

dscpinforepo.exe

subscriber.exe

publisher.exe

file and printer sharing

control panel -> \Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings

allow file sharing for used network type (Domain/public/private)